# Return multiple lines in web.py

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, web.py

I got my data out of MySQL using MySQLdb, however when I try to display them in the webpage using web.py with JSON

```
fetch_resu = cur.fetchall()
json_list = []
for each_tup in fetch_resu:
    json_list.append(each_tup)
return json.dumps(json_list, encoding="UTF-8", ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I will get a bunch of data stuck in one line in the web page (which same sentence run perfectly in local debugging)

Since I can only return data, how could I make them prettier?
Or shall I use template? But my database is dynamicly changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, there are two options.

- surround the content with `<pre>..</pre>` or `<code>..</code>`

OR

- respond as a `text/plain` content-type:

  ```
  web.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  return json.dumps(...)
  ```

Comment: The `text/plain` works, seems like I need learn more HTML before going further